# Ceiling in LaTeX

Tags: equations

I want to make an equation that use ceiling, and that's what I'm doing:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}
\begin{equation}
\ceil[\big]{\frac{log{(1-P_{0})}}{log{(1-p)}}}
\end{equation}
```

The result is not as good as I want it:

[image]

How do I make the ceiling cover the whole fractions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you tried something other than `\big`?

Comment: you are right it worked

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Comment: you don't keep it for other people ?

Comment: @StefanPinnow don't close it as *off-topic* (because it is not). Either find the duplicate question that this must be or it is a valid question which even has been answered already…

Comment: you also need a backslash on your \log(.) function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should read some guides (starter guides) for LaTeX and math (especially about the sizes). With the knowledge about them you could easily adapt to this (`\bigg`):

[image: ceiling]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\ceil[\bigg]{\frac{\log{(1-P_{0})}}{\log{(1-p)}}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I'm new to latex and i have dead line to follow that's why I had no time to adapt for this first.

Comment: @elia You're welcome. But as I already posted: The usual strategy to say thank you is to use the upvote or accept button (if it works for you).

Comment: bro I know but i can't vote until 10 Min pass, I'll surly select your answer

Comment: Please, please change both instances of `log` to `\log`.

Comment: @Mico Done. But the important part of the answer isn't the code, but the reference to starter guides ;)

Answer (score 9):

Very simple, you can work with the asterisk.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \ceil*{\frac{\log (1-P_{0})}{\log (1-p)}}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I also applied some minor improvements on `log` vs `\log`.

[image]

Please consider the manual http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools .

Just for adding some informal tags: *Kenneth Eugene Iverson floor ceiling notation*.

Comment: I like the »[asterix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterix)« but I guess you meant *asterisk*? ;)

Comment: That is a Freudian slip. I demand to introduce *asterix* as a synonym for *asterisk*. Didn't Knuth introduced the word *perm* for *permutation*?